# MapBox attribution is spilling off to the side of the map

Tags: javascript, css, mapbox

How do I reposition the mapbox attribution text? I have this:

```
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  accessToken: '...',
  container: 'map',
  center: [16.572149246748594, 19.06111670348622],
  zoom: 1.5,
  style: 'mapbox://styles/my/map',
  attributionControl: false,
})
.addControl(new mapboxgl.AttributionControl({
  compact: true
}), 'top-left')
```

But it is not having any effect, and it is just to the bottom left *outside* of the map. How do i fix this?

[image]

I am using their NPM package not the `<script>` version, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Seems to have been fixed, maybe it was just a temporary bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have to include

```
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';
```

That's what I forgot to do.